# SQL Query to convert Particular Rows into Column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, window-functions, gaps-and-islands

Suppose the data

```
ID          Date                    Mode
1           2019-09-20 09:28      IN
2           2019-09-20 19:00      IN
3           2019-09-20 19:00      IN
4           2019-09-20 19:00      IN
5           2019-09-20 19:01      IN
6           2019-09-20 19:01      IN
7           2019-09-20 19:01      Out
8           2019-09-20 20:28      IN
9           2019-09-20 20:35      IN
10          2019-09-20 20:50      Out
11          2019-09-20 20:55      Out
12          2019-09-20 21:30      IN
```

convert into rows of period which is minimum check-in TO maximum check-out

I used iteration to achieved desire result but want a optimize query (set base or CTE) to increase performance,

This is what I want

```
ID      DateIN              ID          DateOut
01      2019-09-20 09:28    07          2019-09-20 19:01
08      2019-09-20 20:28    11          2019-09-20 20:55
```

Comment: Are you sure you are using SQL Server 2008?  It is no longer supported.

Answer (score 2):

This is a gaps-and-island based problem.

To start with, you can generate groups of consecutive records with the following query:

```
SELECT [Mode], MIN(id) min_id, MAX(id) max_id, MIN([Date]) min_date, MAX([Date]) max_date
FROM (
    SELECT
        id,
        [Date],
        [Mode],
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY [Date]) rn1,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [Mode] ORDER BY [Date]) rn2
    FROM mytable
) x
GROUP BY [Mode], (rn1 - rn2)
```

This yields:

```
Mode | min_id | max_id | min_date         | max_date        
:--- | -----: | -----: | :--------------- | :---------------
IN   |      1 |      6 | 2019-09-20 09:28 | 2019-09-20 19:01
Out  |      7 |      7 | 2019-09-20 19:01 | 2019-09-20 19:01
IN   |      8 |      9 | 2019-09-20 20:28 | 2019-09-20 20:35
Out  |     10 |     11 | 2019-09-20 20:50 | 2019-09-20 20:55
IN   |     12 |     12 | 2019-09-20 21:30 | 2019-09-20 21:30
```

Then, you can turn this query to a cte and self-join it to generate the expected resultset:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT [Mode], MIN(id) min_id, MAX(id) max_id, MIN([Date]) min_date, MAX([Date]) max_date
    FROM (
        SELECT
            id,
            [Date],
            [Mode],
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY [Date]) rn1,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [Mode] ORDER BY [Date]) rn2
        FROM mytable
    ) x
    GROUP BY [Mode], (rn1 - rn2)
)
SELECT c1.min_id IdIn, c1.min_date DateIN, c2.max_id IdOut, c2.max_date DateOut
FROM cte c1
INNER JOIN cte c2 
    ON  c1.mode = 'IN'
    AND c2.mode = 'Out'
    AND c2.min_id = c1.max_id + 1
```

Output:

```
IdIn | DateIN           | IdOut | DateOut         
---: | :--------------- | ----: | :---------------
   1 | 2019-09-20 09:28 |     7 | 2019-09-20 19:01
   8 | 2019-09-20 20:28 |    11 | 2019-09-20 20:55
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=ebed18b44d5888aa32325ad658a18bf9)**

Comment: INSERT INTO mytable(ID,Date,Mode) VALUES (2,'2019-09-20 19:00','IN');
INSERT INTO mytable(ID,Date,Mode) VALUES (3,'2019-09-20 19:00','Out');
INSERT INTO mytable(ID,Date,Mode) VALUES (6,'2019-09-20 19:01','IN');
INSERT INTO mytable(ID,Date,Mode) VALUES (7,'2019-09-20 19:01','Out');
INSERT INTO mytable(ID,Date,Mode) VALUES (8,'2019-09-20 20:28','IN');
INSERT INTO mytable(ID,Date,Mode) VALUES (9,'2019-09-20 20:35','IN');
INSERT INTO mytable(ID,Date,Mode) VALUES (10,'2019-09-20 20:50','Out');
INSERT INTO mytable(ID,Date,Mode) VALUES (11,'2019-09-20 20:55','IN');

Answer (score 0):

You can try this below option using CTE-

You can check [DEMO HERE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=0cb98a8618e3033b468c3735ed22d51d)

```
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT A.id,A.Date,A.Mode
    FROM your_table A
    LEFT JOIN your_table  B ON A.ID = B.ID - 1
    WHERE A.Mode <> B.Mode OR (A.Mode = 'In' AND B.Mode = 'In')
)

SELECT 
(
    SELECT MIN (ID) 
    FROM CTE
    WHERE ID > (SELECT ISNULL(MAX(ID),0) FROM CTE WHERE ID < A.ID AND mode = 'Out') 
    AND ID < A.ID
) [ID],
(
    SELECT MIN (Date) 
    FROM CTE 
    WHERE ID > (SELECT ISNULL(MAX(ID),0) FROM CTE WHERE ID < A.ID AND mode = 'Out') 
    AND ID < A.ID
) [In],
A.ID,A.Date [Out]
FROM CTE A
WHERE A.Mode = 'Out'
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server 2008 is no longer a supported product.  All supported versions of SQL Server support `lag()` and `lead()`.

You can readily use these functions for this purpose.  There is a simple observation:

- You want an `'IN'` record when the previous record is `'OUT'` (or doesn't exist).
- You want an `'OUT'` record when the next record is `'IN'`  (or doesn't exist)

Once you have filtered to these records, you can just take each `'OUT'` record and the previous `'IN'` values for the final result:

```
select prev_id, prev_dt as date_in, id, dt as date_out
from (select io.*,
             lag(dt) over (order by dt) as prev_dt,
             lag(id) over (order by dt) as prev_id
      from (select t.*,
                   lag(mode) over (order by dt) as prev_mode,
                   lead(mode) over (order by dt) as next_mode
            from t
           ) io
      where mode = 'IN' and (prev_mode is null or prev_mode = 'OUT') or
            mode = 'OUT' and (next_mode is null or next_mode = 'IN')
     ) io
where mode = 'OUT';
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=6a4145198e01c079b2ef19665f8d1113) is a db<>fiddle.

I offer this because just using `lag()`/`lead()` with no aggregation or `join`s is likely to have better performance than alternatives.